# Formatting date (time) in a string

Tags: c#, string, datetime, format

I have a very stupid question.

When the end-user plans an action, the planned time must be visible on the usercontrol of the action like this (hh:mm). On every site I find about formatting dates into a string, they say to use {0:h} or {0:hh}. In my following code I do the same thing, it just doesn't work.

When the end-user plans an action, the returned string is now "Planned Start Date - HH:DD".

```
lblStartDatePlanned.Content = String.Format("Planned Start Date - {0:hh}:{1:dd}", date.Hour, date.Minute);
```

Object date is of type DateTime.

Anyone knows what is wrong? I don't want to waste too much time on such a small thing.
Thanks!

Comment: Remember, there are no stupid questions - just stupid people :)  (A  joke by the way - and a reference to South park, so no offence was intended - it's not a stupid question :) )

Comment: Hehe, thanks :). It's just annoying wasting time on small 'problems' like this.

Comment: In my opinion, a *stupid question* is a question to which the answer is obvious or can easily be answered on one's own. This question is neither, so it's not a stupid question ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
lblStartDatePlanned.Content = String.Format("Planned Start Date - {0:HH:mm}", date);
```

Comment: I suggested something but this is better

Comment: @DanielDawes, I suggested the same as you, and also agree with this.

Answer (score 1):

Generically, if you're trying to force 2 digits in a format string, you can also use:

```
String.Format("Planned Start Date - {0:00}:{1:00}", date.Hour, date.Minute);
```

Although, @Alessandro's answer is correct for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
lblStartDatePlanned.Content = date.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```